# Calculate complexity of algorithm

Tags: heap, complexity-theory, priority-queue

I wrote this algorithm which has to a `O(logn)` complexity.
The first while loops into the arrayList until he find the element with the right value and complexity. I organized the arraylist like an heap. In the second while the elements of the arraylist are reordered according to their priority. Has the first loop complexity `O(n)` `O(logn)`?

```js
  public void increasePriority(T value, int oldPriority, int newPriority) throws PriorityQueueException {
    if (c.compare(oldPriority, newPriority) > 0) 
        throw new PriorityQueueException("The new priority is lower than the current one");
    int i = getSize() - 1;
    while (i > 0 && !(queue.get(i).getPriority() == oldPriority && queue.get(i).getValue() == value)) {
      i = getParent(i);
    }
    if (i == 0) throw new PriorityQueueException("Element (" + value + "," + oldPriority +") doesn't exits in the queue");
    queue.get(i).setPriority(newPriority);
    while (i > 0 && c.compare(queue.get(i).getPriority(), queue.get(getParent(i)).getPriority()) > 0) {
      swap(i, getParent(i));
      i = getParent(i);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your arraylist is structured as a heap, then the first loop has complexity O(log n). It starts at the last node and then moves up the heap. Each change of level divides `i` by 2.

As written, your `increasePriority` method will not work, because it won't necessarily find the node you're looking for. It doesn't look at every node in the heap. For example, given this heap:

```
        1
     2     3
   4   5 6   7
```

It will start at node 7, then look at 3, and then look at 1. If you were looking for any other value, your algorithm wouldn't find it.

You have to do a sequential search of the arraylist to find the item. Then you can use the second loop to change the priority.

So *finding* the node to change is O(n). Changing the priority once you find it is O(log n). That makes the complexity O(n) + log(n), and because log(n) is very small when compared to n, especially as n becomes large, we call that `O(n)`.